# "Collection if" in Python

Tags: python

Dart has a neat feature called [collection if](https://dart.dev/language/collections#control-flow-operators). It lets you conditionally include an element in a list literal. For example:

```
var nav = ['Home', 'Furniture', 'Plants', if (promoActive) 'Outlet'];
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this in Python? The best I can come up with is:

```
nav = ['Home', 'Furniture', 'Plants', *(['Outlet'] if promoActive else [])];
```

But that sucks. Is there something clearer?

Edit: To be clear, I want it to work in the situations where you can use an array literal. `.append()` is going to be horrible for situations like this:

```
a = {
  "foo": {
     "bar": [
        ["a"],
        ["b", "c", *(["d"] if foo else []), "e", "f"],
        ...
```

Comment: Python does not provide an `if` without the `else` as an expression, only the `if` block can omit the `else`.

Comment: no way directly supported like this in the literal syntax. I would probably just use `if promoActive: nav.append("Outlet")`

Comment: You could always add your own utility function to hide this but generally would be better to add it separately - ie. `*collection_if(promo_active, "Outlet")`

Comment: One could try `['Home', 'Furniture', 'Plants', *['Outlet'] * promoActive]`, but for the mercy of BDFL, just write a conditional `append` :)

Comment: The trouble with `append` is that you can't do it in the middle of a big literal (imagine if this was inside a dictionary), and you also might not be appending. This could be in the middle.

Comment: The big literal would only mean that you need to prepare the data before defining it and then pass it into the big literal as a separate variable

Comment: @Sayse Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

In python use the following This appends the list ['Outlet'] to nav only if promoActive is True

```
nav = ['Home', 'Furniture', 'Plants'] + (['Outlet'] if promoActive else [])
```

Comment: That's basically the same as the answer I suggested.

Answer (score -2):

You can use if else expression, and filter out specific elements afterwards:

```
promoActive = True
nav = ['Home', 'Furniture', 'Plants', 'Outlet' if promoActive else None]
nav = [e for e in nav if e is not None]

print(nav) # ['Home', 'Furniture', 'Plants', 'Outlet']
```

If you don't want None elements in your list (e.g. to not break the typing), you can use `''` instead.

```
promoActive = True
nav = ['Home', 'Furniture', 'Plants', 'Outlet' if promoActive else '']
nav = [e for e in nav if e]

print(nav) # ['Home', 'Furniture', 'Plants', 'Outlet']
```

Comment: I think this is worse than my solution from a hassle point of view. But either way it has a bigger issue - the type of `nav` is now inferred as `list[str | None]`.

Comment: As for hassle, I'd say it's worth it as `'Outlet' if promoActive else ''` in my opinion looks bit cleaner than `*(['Outlet'] if promoActive else [])`, and final filter needs to be run only once

Comment: That obviously won't work if empty strings (or other "null"-placeholders for other data types) can be found among other values.